# Error 'mongodump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: mongodb

I have read the documentation and followed the steps to run mongodump on windows machine, but still getting this error.

I tried to set the path using this command `set path="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin"` and added the path in environmental variables but still getting the error. What should I do ?

Comment: set path in cmd to bin folder or go to that bin folder and open cmd from there, and try that command.

Comment: I tried both and still. Also restarted my PC several times

Comment: have you downloaded [mongodb tools](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools)? if not than please download it. and try accessing that command

Comment: yep I downloaded it also

Comment: It should work, you are probably missing something.